# Turing machine that checks whether a given string is an output of a given machine and input

Tags: turing-machines, computability, undecidability, kolmogorov-complexity

Is there a Turing machine such that, given a description $\langle M \rangle$ of a Turing machine $M$, an input $x$ and a string $y$, computes whether or not $y$ is the output of $M$ input $x$?

My guess is that the answer is no because this might imply that the set of strings with Kolmogorov complexity greater than or equal to their length is decidable.

Comment: What's the output of a machine that never halts?

Comment: If M input x does not halt then for any y the machine would answer that y is not an output of M input x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Any such machine  $T^*$ would allow you to immediately solve the halting problem.
Given a description of $M$, construct a Turing machine $T_M$ that simulates $M$ and then outputs some fixed string, e.g., "0". Notice that, given $M$, $T_M$ is computable.

Then $T^*$ with input $T_M$ and "0" accepts if $M$ halts and rejects if $M$ does not halt.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm a mathematician that knows very little about computability. What exactly does it mean that it "simulates" M?

Comment: $T_M$ is just a Turing machine that behaves exactly like $M$ until $M$ returns, and then does some more things (i.e., it erases the tape and writes a single "0"). A description of $T_M$ can be derived from a description for $M$. Alternatively, a $T_M$ can "execute" (simulate) $M$ directly from its description. See [Universal Turing Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_machine) for the details.

Comment: I think I got it, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

No, in fact any non-trivial semantic property of Turing machines is undecidable. This result is [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).